# Snapshot backup size increase after starting transactional replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, transactional-replication

The size of the snapshot backups went from 1.6 GB to 16 GB one week later after starting transactional replication. Does anyone know why this might be happening? I'm using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: This is off topic here, but you'll need to add more information like exactly what kind of backups you are taking, and what the replication topology is.

Comment: What are the 'sync with backup' options for both your publisher and distribution database? The relevant one is if it's set to true at the distribution database which will quote "Setting this option on the distribution database ensures that transactions in the log of the publication database will not be truncated until they have been backed up at the distribution database." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/administration/strategies-for-backing-up-and-restoring-snapshot-and-transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver15